# How to accept the JSON data of Response Cards from Amazon Lex in android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am developing a android app where user interacts with the Amazon Lex chatbot. So now i have created the response cards at aws console and i want those response cards to be displayed in the chat window where the user and chatbot are interacting.

I am using the method **TextInForTextOut** for sending text data and as the name suggests i get a response in text format. But now when i put send some text, i should be able to get a response card in reply to that text.

So my question is how do i get the data related to response cards from Lex and how do i accept it and show it or display it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same problem, apparently I ended up writing my own library: https://github.com/PikkaPikkachu/lex-app for that purpose. Works the same way as aws-lex-sdk, but instead of Response, I have included the TextResponse class, which sends a Post Text Request to Lex.